# Changing keyboard in UIAutomation

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I am testing my app. There I have a textfield, where first I enter letters, then I change keyboard to numbers and enter numbers, so that I get a string `qwerty123`. But UIAutomation doesn't understand this. When I run this script it says `"tap point object is required"` at the line `"target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("qwerty123\n");"` How can I explain to it that the keyboard has changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the textfield value with setValue which will bring the keyboard window and tap the done element in the keyboard

`textfield.setValue(addressLink);
target.frontMostApp().keyboard().elements()["done"].tap();`

```
You can also do following
```

`target.frontMostApp().keyboard().elements()["q"].tap();
     target.frontMostApp().keyboard().elements()["w"].tap();
     target.frontMostApp().keyboard().elements()["more"].tap();
     target.frontMostApp().keyboard().elements()["1"].tap();
     target.frontMostApp().keyboard().elements()["2"].tap();
     target.frontMostApp().keyboard().elements()["done"].tap();`

Comment: It's case sensitive. It should be "Done", not "done"

Answer (score 0):

To set any string, just use the following:

```
window.secureTextFields()[0].setValue(""); //Sets textfield to empty. 
app.keyboard().typeString(qwerty123); //Type any string you want
app.keyboard().typeString("\n"); //Press 'Enter'. Also can go in the above line.
```